# Добавить аргумент для Bash скрипта

Tags: linux, c, bash

есть bash скрипт. 
как мне добавить в него аргументы? 
т.к  
при запуске 
 `./script1 [аргумент1] [аргумент2]` 
что - то подобное.

Comment: Особым образом объявлять не  надо. Обращаться к ним: $1 -- аргумент 1, $2 -- аргумент 2 и т.д. до 9. Если хотите большего -- прочитайте в конце-концов `man bash`

Comment: a="$1"
b="$2"

echo $a $b


./script1 lol lal
уже нашел, но спс за совет про man bash

Comment: @alexanderbarakin дубликат ли? Здесь речь об отдельном скрипте, а не о функции.

Comment: @D-side, фактически, один из вопросов — просто уточнённый/переформулированный вариант другого. на один из вопросов уже даны ответы. по-моему, они идеально соответствуют и данному вопросу.